# "submit for review" is disabled for in-app purchase product

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

Based on all the steps mentioned here http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/, I have created a new application, uploaded its' binary and rejected it. I also added a product but its status is in "Ready to Submit" and the top right button "submit for review" is disabled. Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe due to [this](http://macdailynews.com/2011/05/18/following-lodsys-legal-threats-apple-reportedly-stops-approving-ios-apps-with-in-app-purchases/)

in short: Lodsys has been threatening developers using in-app purchases about a patent they own and apple has licensed (but the license does not extend to developers), apple is investigating...

Comment: Looks like Apple has responded to Lodsys:
http://www.fiercedeveloper.com/story/apple-lodsys-app-purchase-patent-license-covers-ios-developers-too/2011-05-23

Comment: More developments with Apple and Lodsys:
http://moconews.net/article/419-apple-wants-to-take-the-bite-out-of-lodsys-suit/

Answer (score 5):

I just noticed this same thing yesterday as well. I stumbled around for a while and then I noticed that in the Add Version page for your new binary, there is a list of the In App Purchases you can submit for review along with the binary. Checking those In App Purchases and submitting the binary has moved the In App Purchases to the Waiting for Review state. It is confusing that the In App Purchase page has a grayed out Submit For Review button when I never had to click it.

Answer (score 2):

check-out http://www.macstories.net/news/apple-temporarily-freezing-in-app-purchase-approvals/ . It has some indications and links to further info.

Answer (score 2):

for itunes page in 2018. if your in-app purchase is ready for review stage. you should go to your app and click  prepare for submission then scroll down the page until you see the In-App Purchases  section. click blue button and add your in app purchase you created before.