# iTunes Connect : Unable to save changes for uploading new binary

Tags: iphone, upload, binary, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have submitted a new version of my application in order to include in-App-Purchase 3 month ago and it has been rejected. I have worked on it and now I'm trying to upload the new binary for validation.

Here are the steps I'm doing in iTunes Connect :

- Select the button "Ready To Upload Binary"
- Select the different options (about encryption stuff and "I will release...")

And When I try to save, I always get this error message (for the last 8 days): 
**The following error(s) occurred**:
**We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later**.

So I can't upload the new binary and submit my new version :(

I didn't get any answer from iTunes Connect support yet...

I've tried from different browsers as I saw in forums but it still doesn't work.

Since the last update which was rejected, I have just added keywords, new screenshots and In-App-Purchase products in the metadata. Also my app is now universal (working for iPhone and iPad).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

After getting the "The following error(s) occurred: We're temporarily unable to save your changes. Please try again later." when trying to save changes to an application update about ten times in a row just now (retrying every 30 seconds or so), I clicked the "< My Apps" link to go back to my list of apps.

At that point, the iTunes Connect website popped up a dialog along the lines of "You'll lose your changes, do you wish to save?"  I figured, sure, why not try it, and clicked the Save button on the popup -- and this time, the save worked!

No idea if that was a fluke or not, but it's something to try!

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057337/submit-for-review-is-disabled-for-in-app-purchase-product/6057387#6057387).

in short: Lodsys has been threatening developers using in-app purchases about a patent they own and apple has licensed (but the license does not extend to developers), apple is investigating...